# Handling generated urls in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making a link shortener as part of a school project,

```
Route::get('{short_url}', array('uses' => 'UrlController@shortUrlRedirect');
```

This function works fine alone, but as I have other functions such as

```
Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doRegister'));
```

whenever example.com/anylink

is now used, it is handled by one function alone.

A working solution I found would be to do something like:

```
Route::get('url/{short_url}', array('uses' => 'UrlController@shortUrlRedirect');
```

But of course with a link shortener, the goal is to have as little characters as possible.

Any ideas of a possible way to handle this issue within laravel?

Comment: Do you have your `{short_url}` route at the bottom of the file?

Comment: Not currently, is the routing listed in order of priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earlier or 'higher' in the `routes.php` file is the route, the more priority it gets, so if you define two identical routes or two routes that match one pattern, like in your example, the first one will be executed.

So you should define `register` route earlier, as it should not be overriden by the `{short_url}`.

Here is the explanation: Routes: [First in, first out](http://laravel.io/topic/30/routes-first-in-first-out)

**TL;DR:** Laravel receives a request, and uses the URI of the request to find a matching pattern iterating the routes file, when it finds one, it `break;`s the loop.